# MKAnnotationView problems self initializiers (convert swift 2.0 to swift 2.3)

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I'm right now transferring an iOS app from Swift 2.0 to 2.3 and run into Problems on very simple thing...

that's my AnnotationView class:

```
class PPLocationAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    private let annotationSize = CGSize(width: 60.0, height: 60.0)

    init() {
        let annotationFrame = CGRect(
            origin: CGPointZero,
            size: annotationSize)
        super.init(frame: annotationFrame)

        opaque = true
        image = UIImage.annotationLocationIcon()
        enabled = true
        canShowCallout = false
        centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -(UIImage.annotationLocationIcon().size.height / 2) + 10.0)

        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    }
}
```

The Error which occures is:
"Must call a designated initializer of the superclass MKAnnotationView"

So i changed this bit to:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        let annotationFrame = CGRect(
            origin: CGPointZero,
            size: annotationSize)
        self.init(frame: annotationFrame)
```

Now i get a new Error: "use of 'self' in method call 'setupAudioSession' before super.init initializes self"

i don't get it...

would be great if some could help with that.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designated initializer of a MKAnnotationView is `init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?)`

You need to call that in your initializer.